# Shopify staging webshop authentication

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I'm running a shopify webshop and the API is working fine example:

https://91a2177209f5ce022394b7309c506010:c3766eb1c9e4a8586d934aca15f26b51@myshop.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-04/orders.json

Now I've setup a staging shop here https://developers.shopify.com/. Like my production shop I've created a [private app](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/apps/private-apps), when I use those keys for authentication like my production site it keeps asking for a username and password (when I enter the url in the browser). Why is this and how can I fix this?

(data is fake)

Comment: Please don't share your username and password, this is a huge security risk! Don't use them in front-end request as well, your store will be open to outside attacks. Check your private app permissions, you may not have permissions to read orders.

Comment: It's fake data :), and all permissions are given.

Comment: Use `api/2020-07` instead of `api/2020-04`, there seems to be an issue with `2020-04` private app at the moment. The same problem happens to me as well when I tested it with 2020-04, but it works with 2020-07.

Comment: @drip thanks dude, that helps me a lot! Working now.